# Vagrant with window sub system not working

Tags: vagrant, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vagrant-windows

When I run `vagrant up` I get following error on bash:

> Vagrant cannot currently enable access to manage machines within the Windows
>   environment because the version of Vagrant installed on Windows does not
>   match this version of Vagrant running within the Windows Subsystem for Linux.
>   Please ensure both installation of Vagrant are the same. If you do not want
>   update your Vagrant installations you can disable Windows access by unsetting
>   the `VAGRANT_WSL_ACCESS_WINDOWS_USER` environment variable.
>
> Windows Vagrant version: unknown
>
> Windows Subsystem for Linux Vagrant version: 1.9.5

[image: Check Screenshot]

```
System environment
OS :  Windows 10
Windows Vagrant version : 1.9.5
VirtualBox version : VirtualBox-5.1.26-117224-Win
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: probably you should get more information than this, what is the exact error you get after running `vagrant` command?

Comment: I have attached screenshot in question. please check

Answer (score -1):

For Vagrant setup there are tow things we should consider

*• Make sure that **VT virtualization** is enabled in BIOS settings if not then. Turn on Intel VT virtualization in BIOS settings and restart the machine*

•   *Make sure that **hyper-v** is not Enabled. Stop hyper-v service running by default in Windows 8/10, since it blocks all other calls to VT hardware.  To do that  go to
Control Panel -> Program And Features -> Turn Windows Features on or off.*